# Interfacing Tinyduino BLE Module and Phonegap To send Serial Data

Tags: android, ios, cordova, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was wondering if someone could help me out? I am currently running the phonegap desktop and mobile apps. I currently have a BLE board for an a tinyduino. The board is discoverable by BLE discovery applications such as lightblue. In order to achieve  this I have used the example [HERE](https://tiny-circuits.com/learn/tinyshield-ble2)

**Note the Tinyduino uses the same IDE as Arduino**

Along with the BLE board i have 3 sensors attached to my Arduino which are all working fine in the serial monitor.

I would like to use phonegap to create a basic application that receives and displays the serial data from the sensors.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of those plugins for Cordova/Phonegap:

Cordova BLE Plugin
https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble

Bluetooth LE Cordova Plugin
https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE

Have in mind that the target device should support Bluetooth LE

Comment: Hello Philip have you ever used these plugins? I found this plugin https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial have you ever seen or used that one?

Comment: Sorry, i haven't use that plugin (only evothings on ios) but i believe it should be ok for use with tinyshield. Have you tried the examples included?

Comment: Yes I have, but i just cant seem to get it to work. Using the simple serial example https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/tree/master/examples/SimpleSerial I see that it says that I must change the UUID which i did and still no luck cannot connect to the program.

Comment: It's everything connected correct? do you get any errors, or any response? Also have you tried to connect the board with an already build app (just to clear if it's the board or your code)?

Comment: You should check this guide also for the BlueGiga, they have some apps that you can use for testing: https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/23007217--TROUBLESHOOTING-Unable-to-discover-BLE112-in-iOS-device-s-Bluetooth-Settings-page

Comment: The board is connecting and displaying information on applications like Evothings and Light Blue. My issue is getting a phonegap application to connect to the BLE board. From what i understand the application must initiate the connection.

Comment: Philip have you ever used the phonegap developer app?

Comment: After much research i have discovered that 3rd party plugins are not supported by the phonegap developer app. I have since started using the phonegap CLI to create projects, add platforms and plugins but i have had no luck so far with getting bluetooth to work i am currently using [This Plugin] (https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) I am using an IOS device because they support BLE more widely than android devices.